# Is it possible to trigger a Databricks job from Airflow, which will consume a Python project I deployed?

Tags: airflow, databricks, databricks-workflows

[Following this tutorial](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/07/19/integrating-apache-airflow-with-databricks.html), I can give the task a path to a notebook I want to run in Databricks -

```
notebook_task_params = {
    'new_cluster': new_cluster,
    'notebook_task': {
        'notebook_path': '/Users/airflow@example.com/PrepareData',
    },
}
```

But is there a way to tell the task to take a Python project (or maybe a path to a wheel file?) from S3 or Artifactory and run it instead of a notebook?

How can I make it work so it will be ready for production? I want to create a process so that after I push my change to the git repo, a CI/CD process will build the project, deploy it to S3/Artifactory, and trigger a Databricks job from Airflow, which consumes the project I deployed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Airflow provider for Databricks support all task/job types provided by the Databricks REST API. If you want to run Python file, then you can use the `spark_python_task` parameter ([doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/_api/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks/index.html#airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks.DatabricksSubmitRunOperator)) to specify a path to the file. If you need to run a wheel file, then you can either use the `spark_submit_task`, or provide a `python_wheel_task` object inside the `json` parameter that is used to fill the data for submission to REST API as we don't support this task yet in Airflow. Refer to the [Databricks REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit) docs for more information what parameters of this task you need to specify.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please provide an example? I really couldn't understand the DB doc for how to submit a job properly to the spark-submit. For example, they mentioned that ```In the new_cluster specification, libraries and spark_conf are not supported. Instead, use --jars and --py-files to add Java and Python libraries and --conf to set the Spark configuration.``` but didn't specify in which script I should add these ```py-files, conf, and py-files``` parameters - in the ```new_cluster``` json or in the ```parameters``` json

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex Ott said, the `python_wheel_task` argument is not available yet in `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`.

However, you can do it using the (multi) `tasks` argument. Like below:

```
trigger_wheel = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
                task_id = 'trigger_wheel',
                tasks = [{"task_key": 'my_task',
                          "python_wheel_task": {
                                'package_name':'wheel_package_name',
                                'entry_point':'wheel_entry_point',
                                }, 
                          "new_cluster":cluster_config,
                          "libraries":[{"whl": "dbfs:/.../wheel_package_name-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl"}]
                         }]
                )
```

My example uses dbfs, but ofcourse you can use a wheel that is on S3. Just make sure your cluster has access to it.

You can also check [Databricks DBX](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This allows you to develop in an IDE and deploy your package easily as a Databricks job (E.g. a job that executes a wheel).